# Is it correct to have the same button in several areas of your application?

Tags: buttons, user-expectation, layout

Imagine an application with an `Employee` register option in its header, but when you click another header option (let's say, `Salaries`), there is a button to register employees inside of the `Salaries` window, and it goes on and on, every window that has the minimum relationship with employees has this button entitled `Add Employee`.

#### Question:

Is this a good or bad practice as far as the user experience is concerned? My concern is that the user will feel like they're lost inside of the application

Comment: This question isn't clear enough, so I don't really understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If it feels like to be not intuitive understandable for the user think about refactoring, it worth the effort.

In your case may be it would be better to put the "Add Employee" feature into the main navigation if it is so important and has no intent to lead a user to the next screen.

If there is some process behind the screens, ask the users about it and try to figure it out for them. 
For example, consider “Add employee” action only in the very beginning of some chain of steps.

In another pattern, if the “Add employee” feature is independent, users often would like to be redirected to the main overview of employees to confirm that the employee was really created.

May be it would also be a good solution to add some confirmation button (“Save”, “Confirm” or “Submit”) to every screen like Salary instead of “Add employee” button and redirect to the main screen.